# Keith Wood Countdown - UK

Tags: c#, jquery

I'm using Keith Wood's countdown.

http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Runs perfectly fine on our servers is US, but when I deploy to our host in the UK. It displays 0 hours, 0 minutes. Any ideas?

```
$(function () {
    var SunriseDate = new Date("@ViewBag.sunrise");
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ until: SunriseDate, format: 'HM' });
});
```

Comment: What's `ViewBag.sunrise`?

Comment: Probably because the `ViewBag.sunrise` string is in UK date format, which cannot be parsed by `Date()`.

Comment: Viewbag.sunrise is the datetime of the next sunrise. Example: 05/08/2015 5:19 AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the UK server will set the date format to `DD/MM/YYYY`, whereas the JS `Date()` constructor can only accept strings if they are in US date format - `MM/DD/YYYY`.

To fix this, you would need to manually set the format of the Date in the `ViewBag` to a US formatted string. Try this:

```
ViewBag.sunrise = SunriseDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");  
// = "05/08/2015 05:19"
```

You would obviously need to change `SunriseDate` in this example to whatever the source is of your original Date value.

Alternatively you can use the `g` FormatString, while providing an `en-US` culture to the `ToString` method:

```
ViewBag.sunrise = SunriseDate.ToString("g", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
// = "05/08/2015 5:19 AM"
```